# Spring Boot Elastic Seemingly ignoring second Query

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have some code I've written which I need a review of (if possible) as I know I have a bug somewhere. Most likely due to my (lack) of understanding of some concepts in ElasticSearch and Spring.

For context:
I have a simple Spring boot API which allows students to add their college projects. These projects are stored in ES which I'm trying to make searchable.

FWIW, From a use case POV, a user can search for a project with a query string which is based on a projectName or a hashtag for the project i.e. "Java".

Right now with the code below, if I search for projects which have a given hashtag I can retrieve them no problem. I get exactly the results I'm looking for.

However...once I try to add a second query whereby I want to limit the results to only students who have a userId contained in a ArrayList my search fails. By Fails I mean it returns everything from the index.

```
private Iterable<UserProjects> searchCollegeProjects(Integer page, Integer size, List<String> hashtags, List<String> studentUserIds) {
        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        QueryBuilder projectQueryBuilder = null;
        if (hashtags != null) {
            projectQueryBuilder =
                    QueryBuilders
                            .multiMatchQuery(hashtags.toString(), "projectName", "projectHashtag")
                            .fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO);
        }
        
        BoolQueryBuilder userIdQueryBuilder = null;
        if(studentUserIds!=null) {
            userIdQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("userId.keyword", studentUserIds));
        }

        Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(projectQueryBuilder)
                .withQuery(userIdQueryBuilder)
                .withFilter(boolQuery()
                        .mustNot(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("isDraft", true)))
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size))
                .build();
        SearchHits<UserProjects> projectHits;
        try {
            projectHits =
                    elasticsearchOperations
                            .search(searchQuery, UserProjects.class,
                                    IndexCoordinates.of(elasticProjectsIndex));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error unable to perform search query" + ex);
            throw new GeneralSearchException(ex.toString());
        }
        List<UserProjects> projectMatches = new ArrayList<>();
        projectHits.forEach(srchHit -> {
            projectMatches.add(srchHit.getContent());
        });


        long totalCount = projectHits.getTotalHits();
        Page<UserProjects> resultPage = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
                projectMatches,
                pageRequest,
                () -> totalCount);
        return resultPage;
    }
```

Also below is my POJO for UserProjects:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(indexName = "college.userprojects")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserProjects {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, name ="_id")
    private String projectId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "autocomplete_index", searchAnalyzer = "lowercase" ,name = "projectName")
    private String projectName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, name = "projectHashTag")
    private List<String> projectHashTag;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean, name = "isDraft")
    private Boolean isDraft;

}
```

EDIT: Just to be clear, if I remove this line from the native query:

```
                .withQuery(userIdQueryBuilder)
```

I get back projects (Correctly) which contain the query text in either their projectName or projectHashtag fields. Putting the above line back in will cause the search to return everything.